# cannot access ClassB class file for not found

Tags: android

There is plenty of examples on stackoverflow but none of them is a general answer

here is my problem in Android Studio 3.3.1

in a library I have:

```
public static class ClassA implements InterfaceB {

 public static String method1(parameter p)  { }

}
```

InterfaceB come from jar dependency and is referenced in gradle

```
public interface InterfaceB{ ... }
```

In my App I use:

```
String s = ClassA.method1(p)
```

no error until I try to run and I get

> error: cannot access InterfaceB class file for
>   com.external.jar.InterfaceB not found

Comment: Please attach some code for faster debugging !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

In gradle add dependency with relative path like:

```
implementation files('../MyLibrary/libs/external.jar')
```

Comment: Is this your answer or additional information to the question?

Comment: this is the answer

Comment: Ok just making sure